# 4DM is NP-complete

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np-hard, np, check-my-answer

Is 4DM NP-complete?

An instance of 4DM consists of four disjoint sets X, Y, W and Z of size k, and a set Q of quadruples $Q = \{ (x, y, w, z) \mid x ∈ X, y ∈ Y, w ∈ W, z ∈ Z \}$

Question: Is there a subset $M ⊆ Q$ such that each of the elements of X, Y, W and Z is in exactly one quadruple in M?

The answer I found online: complete.
To show 4 dimensional matching is NP complete, we want to reduce from 3 dimensional matching. The trick is to just pad each triple with an extra coordinate. We need to do this in a way that we don't really change the problem. One way to do this is to just repeat the last coordinate - so that the triple [a, b, c] is mapped to the quadruple [a, b, c, c].

But if we do that isn't W and Z equal? And we want them to be disjoint.

Comment: Just consider them "same but different".

Comment: @Nathaniel I'm confused, how can I do that? Can further explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generaly not a problem to consider a set as a disjoint copy of another. If you consider a set of integers, just say that the first set are blue integers and the other are red integers.

If that is still a problem for you, you can create:
$$Z=\{(w, 0)|w\in W\}$$
or
$$Z = \{\tilde{w}\mid w\in W\}$$
Now $Z$ is kind of a copy of $W$, but not exactly.

Comment: I get it now, thank you!